# Three.js OBJMTLLoader doesn't load maps from .mtl

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a problem using OBJMTLLoader. It loads my model successfully but diffuse and specular maps aren't loaded. Here's the code:

.js file

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
            loader.load( 'models\\Stop_that_train.obj', 'models\\Stop_that_train.mtl', function ( object ) {

                object.position.y = - 80;
                object.rotation.y = Math.PI/3
                scene.add( object );

            } );
```

.mtl file

```
newmtl 19___Default
Ns 10.0000
Ni 1.5000
d 1.0000
Tr 0.0000
Tf 1.0000 1.0000 1.0000 
illum 2
Ka 0.5882 0.5882 0.5882
Kd 0.5882 0.5882 0.5882
Ks 0.6390 0.6390 0.6390
Ke 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
map_ka bts_locomotive_emd_fp7.png
map_kd bts_locomotive_emd_fp7.png
map_ks IMG_3445.png
```

Comment: Is the texture accessible? It looks like it should be in the same directory as the .mtl file. Is that the case?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try without double backslash in the path?

```
'models\Stop_that_train.obj'
'models\Stop_that_train.mtl'
```